# 3d view looks really wonky. All I see is what appears to be the camera view?

Tags: 3d-view

Not sure how I ended up with this view in my 3d view window. I looked at the display in another 3d view and it shows the whole scene, as it should.

I can't see any difference in the display properties.

How did I end up with this wonky view? And, is there a way, short of collapsing that window and re opening it, of getting it back to the "standard" view?

[image]

Comment: check your clip start and end distance

Comment: What's it supposed to look like instead?

Answer (score 4):

You probably wanted to draw a border and accidentally hit <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> instead of what you wanted and drew a clipping border. The magical cutout to help you see clearly in a packed scene. Just hit it again and it should vanish.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html